# How would I use a join to create a view from two tables that displays the COUNT from another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
    CREATE VIEW EMPJOBS AS 
     SELECT EMPLOYEE.employee_id AS ENUM, 
     CONCAT(EMPLOYEE.first_name, 
     ' ' , EMPLOYEE.last_name) AS NAME, 
     EMPLOYEE.email AS EMAIL, 
     COUNT(JOBHISTORY.end_date) AS FINISHEDJOBS
    FROM EMPLOYEE, JOBHISTORY
    WHERE JOBHISTORY.employee_id = EMPLOYEE.employee_id;
```

This is what I have as a statement. I know it's wrong because it displays this:

[image]

It counts end_date all together as one big count. How could I make it count for every separate ENUM?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your sample data and the expected output and also refrain yourself from using images , make use of tables for posting the data

Comment: Still new to everything, thanks for your feedback @hexxx

Comment: use `group by EMPLOYEE.employee_id` at last.

Answer (score 1):

Add `group by` clause at the end.

```
CREATE VIEW EMPJOBS AS 
 SELECT 
     e.employee_id AS ENUM, 
     CONCAT(e.first_name, 
     ' ' , e.last_name) AS NAME, 
     e.email AS EMAIL, 
     COUNT(j.end_date) AS FINISHEDJOBS
FROM EMPLOYEE e 
inner join  JOBHISTORY j
on j.employee_id = e.employee_id
group by 
    e.employee_id
    ,CONCAT(e.first_name,' ', e.last_name)
    ,e.email;
```

As a best practice, try to use proper join syntax to join table instead of using comma. Also put alias for tables names to avoid confusion and readability.

Comment: `Group by e.employee_id,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.email`

Comment: @Hexxx. Thanks. Missed those in `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in this way:

```
CREATE VIEW EMPJOBS AS 
  SELECT EMPLOYEE.employee_id AS ENUM, 
  CONCAT(EMPLOYEE.first_name, ' ' , EMPLOYEE.last_name) AS NAME, 
  EMPLOYEE.email AS EMAIL,
  Select(COUNT(end_date) From JOBHISTORY jh where jh.employee_id = E.employee_id) AS FINISHEDJOBS
 FROM EMPLOYEE E;
```